# Memory Efficient reading + writing of .csv and .xlsx data

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I am looking to implement memory efficient reading and writing of .xlsx/.csv files.

I am currently using phpExcel and am having trouble with large files. (Known issue)

I found the following library for reading: https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

This seems that it will work.

For writing files currently I create an array and then loop the array to output the file. Is this why it uses a lot of memory? What is the best way to not use a lot of memory when writing csv/xlsx when getting data from mysql database using code igniter?

This is what I do now:

```
/* added for excel expert */
function excel_export() {
    $data = $this->Customer->get_all($this->Customer->count_all())->result_object();
    $this->load->helper('report');
    $rows = array();

    $header_row = $this->_excel_get_header_row();
    $header_row[] = lang('customers_customer_id');
    $rows[] = $header_row;

    foreach ($data as $r) {
        $row = array(
            $r->first_name,
            $r->last_name,
            $r->email,
            $r->phone_number,
            $r->address_1,
            $r->address_2,
            $r->city,
            $r->state,
            $r->zip,
            $r->country,
            $r->comments,
            $r->account_number,
            $r->taxable ? 'y' : '',
            $r->company_name,
            $r->person_id
        );
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $content = array_to_spreadsheet($rows);
    force_download('customers_export.'.($this->config->item('spreadsheet_format') == 'XLSX' ? 'xlsx' : 'csv'), $content);
    exit;
}

function array_to_spreadsheet($arr)
{   
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    //Default all cells to text
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

    for($k = 0;$k < count($arr);$k++)
    {
        for($j = 0;$j < count($arr[$k]); $j++)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow($j, $k+1, $arr[$k][$j]);
        }
    }

    if ($CI->config->item('spreadsheet_format') == 'XLSX')
    {
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);       
    }
    else
    {
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);
    }

    ob_start();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    $excelOutput = ob_get_clean();

    return $excelOutput;
}
```

Comment: What sort of size are you talking about? 100MB? 4GB? If you are talking about GBs it will obviously be slow and there are a number of possible issues, one is you are having IO issues. If on Linux, you could try ionice. Is the issue that the creation slows after a certain point?

Comment: 1-5 mb is the file size I am working with